Medical Practice:Professional Life of a Radiation Oncologist
Is a question about the professional life of a radiation oncologist (scope, job description) on topic in medicine SE?
I am a medical student and I am swinging back and forth between specialties (I even went to law school).
Due to my epilepsy I have decided not to risk any surgical specialties. I'd rather not even touch knives or needles.
I can't imagine myself in front of a screen (mictoscope, etc) describing what I see. I just can't write (dictate) a report.
20 years ago visiting the psychiatrist was a safe haven for me but the subjectivity involved irks me (diagnosis, monitoring etc)
So I thought being an internist and specializing in infectious diseases was my only getaway. I am ok with stethoscopes (+electrodes) and touching my patient with my bare(gloved) hands. Internal medicine is a thinking specialty and while I am good with thinking people don't pay you just to think.
Now thinking back I was always curious about radiation oncology due to my own cancer.
But I don't think I could handle the solitude and the loneliness of sitting in a room and drawin/designing a radiation therapy (dosimetry, where is the target, where should the radiation pass from, isodosic areas etc).
I crave direct contact with people (including patients) I am just not likeable/fun.
I am afraid a seizure can create a legal liability (ethical/moral too).
My question would be what does a radiation oncologist do, how is it like to design a radiation therapy, am I fit to do it?
I certainly want to ask my own radiation oncologist (an eventual colleague) but he is either busy or on vacation with his family.

No, it wouldn't be on topic here, but it would be on topic on https://www.reddit.com/r/Radiology/

But medical imaging is only tangential to radiation therapy. At best they are using those images to design the radiation therapy.

@GeorgeNtoulos The people in that group are going to be knowledgeable of the field. It's as close as you're going to get unless you can find a radiation oncology forum somewhere. In any case, my answer remains. Your question would be off topic  in Medical Sciences because it's basically a discussion question, not one with a specific verifiable answer.

Radiology-ModTeam
MOD
•
1h ago
•
Radiation oncology is not radiology.

@GeorgeNtoulos I know that. I was just trying to help.

I thank you earnestly for that. I just copy pasted what the mod there told me.

After a second thought maybe I didn't even need to ask. The answer would be simple brachytherapy (maybe just this word should suffice), implanting radioactive seeds or catheters. I can't see myself doing that with my epilepsy.

@GeorgeNtoulos Radiology would seem the perfect specialty for a doctor with epilepsy.

I could never write (or dictate) a report. I am extremely annoyed when I am misunderstood. What does the bell is ringing, I am washing myself, the kids have not yet arrived mean? Depening on the extralinguistics these utterances can also mean Please open the door, I can't open the door, Don't put the food on the table yet. I usually don't mean any conversational implicatures with my utterances. I am also not good with loneliness and solitude. That is the same reason I couldn't do anatomical pathology, forensic medicine, lab specialties.

@GeorgeNtoulos There is no career in medicine where you can entirely escape the need to communicate with others, therefore you cannot possibly avoid the potential of being misunderstood or misunderstanding others.

@BryanKrause Oral and direct communication works wonders. I might throw a tantrum or two (like how the hell did you understand this from what I was saying) but Oral and Direct Communication helps me a lot. I have immediate feedback (just looking at their faces, or their gestures), they can ask me follow-up questions, I can change the way I communicate on the go. I don't get bogged down by analysis-paralysis (trying to figure out what a person may understand from what I am writing). I have an easier time communicating and thinking on my feet, than carefully planning what I need to communicate.
